# Variable method name in python

Tags: python, qt, variables, methods

I have a dictionnary `fields={}` which contains some field names that I named the Qt comobox objects after. For example keys `combobox1` and `combobox2`, both contain a list with values that I would like to add to the

```
fields={}
fields['combobox1']=['value1','someting else']
fields['combobox2']=['bla','another value']

for key,values in fields.items():
   for value in values:
      Qt_ui. _____key_____ .addItem(value)
```

what is the correct syntax for the last line, so that ____key____ is replaced with the keys from the dictionary? I tried `ui.__getattribute__(key).addItem(value)` but it does't seem to work. Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
TypeError: 'PySide.QtGui.QComboBox.addItem' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide.QtGui.QComboBox.addItem(float)
Supported signatures:
  PySide.QtGui.QComboBox.addItem(PySide.QtGui.QIcon, unicode, QVariant = QVariant())
  PySide.QtGui.QComboBox.addItem(unicode, QVariant = QVariant())
```

Comment: The `ui.__getattribute__(key)` part seems to work. It looks like `value` is seen as a float. Can you print it before calling `Qt_ui....`?

Comment: Yes you are right, it needs to be a string, Problem solved. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact the problem was somewhere else **getattribute**(key) is correct but the added item needs to be a string. Any way, I thought this is an interesting problem and will leave the post anyway.

```
ui.__getattribute__(key).addItem(str(value))
```

Comment: `getattr(ui, key).addItem(value)`.